# How to adjust mouse drag threshold in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

With normal clicking, I'm dragging widgets on web pages by accident.  I need to adjust the mouse drag threshold.  http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/3.3/mouse-drag-threshold.html.en tells me how to do it in gnome. How in Lubuntu?

Please answer for Lubuntu.

**EDIT
i don't have a touchpad.  mouse drag threshold is the distance the mouse moves in pixels before it decides that you are dragging a widget.

Comment: Sorry, it is such a common issue that I assumed touchpad was what you meant. I think I can help with that. Will edit/delete my response depending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you read the [GtkSettings documentation](http://people.gnome.org/~johnp/girdocsalpha/Gtk/Gtk.Settings.html), you can change the settings for GTK3 applications by editing the config file.

I tested this by adding

```
gtk-dnd-drag-threshold = 14
```

to `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`.

After rebooting it works, but not in Firefox, which is where I need it to work.

However, there is [an article](http://web.archive.org/web/20120702060415/http://nanolx.org/newslinux/change-gtk-settings) that describes how to edit `~/.gtkrc-2.0` with the same modification.  and it works.

Comment: You should explain some more background in your question. I have no reason to suppose you went through the steps in your link when answering you unless you make it clear by saying so then.

Comment: I added that line to ~/.gtkrc-2.0 and - wonderful! - Firefox stopped treating 40% of my clicks as drags!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully tested this yet, but I think this shell command does the trick (in Ubuntu 16.04):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse drag-threshold 30
```

Changes take effect immediately, so you can easily test it and don't need to reboot.

Comment: Worked for me. This can be done with dconf-editor (16.04.1 LTS Unity) : on the left pane, expand org, gnome, setting-daemon, peripherals, mouse. On the right panel, change the value of the text field named drag-threshold to 30 (default is 8: it is the distance before a drag is started)

Comment: It is now
`org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse`

instead of
`org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse`

(Ubuntu 22.04)
Seems like it does prevent the dragging, but also does not trigger a click event. So the effect is that if the movement during mouse down and up is between 8 and 30 pixels, then nothing happens (cursor is not moved into the place of click)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should go to `preferences>Keyboard and mouse`.

If the problem is that you don't have this then you need to go to go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install lxinput
```

and then try the first step again.

There are also some additional mouse settings in openbox configuration manager. I think it may be your click that is the issue more than your drag so it might be worth playing with that too. Openbox is also found in preferences.

[image: have a look here]

and here

[image]

Comment: no this is for dragging windows